# From source to destination

Tags: excel, formula

I have a sheet renamed as Chart Strings that has data values in two columns. Column A has the names of the projects that I work on while Column B has the alphanumeric value that is associated with that project. Each month a new sheet is created with Column A representing the project Name, Column B the percentage of time worked on, and column C is supposed to be the alphanumeric value that is associated with that project name. I am trying to use the sheet Chart Strings as a reference sheet that each sheet that represents that month can use to lookup. What i would like to do is to enter the name of the project in the sheet that represents the current month and have it populate the alphanumeric value into Column C on the row that I entered the name of the project in Column A. So essentially it needs to lookup and match the name that is on the reference sheet if that data matches then it will lookup the value in column B that corresponds with that name thus copying the data to the cell in Column C in the month sheet.

I tried a couple of formulas from forums and none panned out the way I expected.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and explain how, exactly, it fails to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use VLOOKUP. The first argument takes an value that you want to look up information about (in this case, the project name) and then scans the first column of a specified table (in this case the table you created on the 'Chart Strings' worksheet in columns A and B) to find that value. Once it does, it returns a corresponding value from another column in the lookup table (in this case the alpha numeric code in the second column, B, of your table).

VLOOKUP(A2,'Chart Strings'!A:B,2,FALSE)

Be sure to use the 'FALSE' condition for matching so you find an exact match.